# Databricks ConvertToDelta - Parquet table to Delta - "AssertionError: assertion failed: File name collisions found"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

```
sampleDf = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'A', 2021, 1, 5),(1, 'B', 2021, 1, 6),(1, 'C', 2021, 1, 7),],['msg_id', 'msg', 'year', 'month', 'day'])
sampleDf.show()
sampleDf.write.format("parquet").option("path", "/mnt/datalake/test").mode("append").partitionBy("msg_id","year", "month", "day").saveAsTable("test_rawais")
```

This results in the following table: 
[image]

Now when I convert this parquet table to a delta table, I get the following error.
[image]

If I directly create a new delta table instead of a 'convert to delta', then it works.
[image]

Any inputs would help.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you working from a clean slate when adding the records to the table? From your screenshot it looks like more data is present than what you defined in your first query. Just remember that a `DROP TABLE` will not delete the data in your case, since you've created an external table.

Comment: @Bram, yes its a clean slate. Hope y're referring to the second image with the error msg. If you see the same set of 3 files are repeated 4 times in the error. In the physical path there are 3 parquet files in total. Thanks.